# Windows Docker Image keeps hanging up randomly on Azure (web-app)

Tags: windows, azure, docker, docker-compose, azure-web-app-service

I won't be able to provide the docker file so I'll try to provide as much context as I can to the issue. I keep running into issues with Azure and Windows based Docker containers randomly. The app will run fine for weeks with no issues and then suddenly bug out (using the same exact image) and go into an endless cycle of "Waiting for container to be start." followed by "Container failed to reach the container's http endpoint".

I have been able to resolve the issue in the past by re-creating the service (again using the same exact image) but it seems this time its not working.

Various Tests:

1. The same exact docker image runs locally no problem
2. As I mentioned, re-creating the service before did the trick (using the same exact image)

Below are the exact steps I have in place:

1. Build a windows based image using a Docker Compose File. I specify in the docker compose file to map ports 2000:2000.
2. Push the Docker Image to a private repository on docker hub
3. Create a web app service in Azure using the image

Any thoughts on why this randomly happens? My only next idea is to re-create the docker image as a Linux based image.

Answer (score 1):

Does your app need to access more than a single port? Please note that as of right now, we only allow a single port. More information on that [here](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-windows-containers/wiki/things-you-should-know#you-can-only-expose-one-port-to-the-outside-world).

Lastly, please see if the turning off the container check, mentioned [here](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-windows-containers/wiki/things-you-should-know#your-container-must-respond-to-an-http-ping), helps to resolve the matter.

Let us know the outcome of these two steps and we can assist you further if needed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I decided to transition over to a Linux based image and everything works as expected.